# How many streams are supported by kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

How can we check like how many streams are supported by a `Kafka` cluster with 3 nodes

My project is related to videos, I am transferring video from source to destination in the form of meta-data using `Kafka`. i.e I am doing some process on the videos then forming metadata and then sending this data to `Kafka` using `Kafka-Producer` API through topic 'test-topic'. I am a consumer class which takes that data(meta-data) and do some process. Like this I have implemented 3`Kafka processors`. I am running each process 6 times for different kind of inputs, so totally I have 18 processors. But here my doubt is not related to Kafka processors. My doubt is related to `Kafka-Cluster`. How streams are related to kafka-cluster and is there any way to know the number of streams supported by a `kafka cluster`.

Answer (score 1):

It will hugely depend on what your application is doing, the throughput, and so on. Some general resources to help you:

- [Elastic Scaling in the Streams API in Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/elastic-scaling-in-kafka-streams/)
- [Kafka Streams Capacity planning and sizing](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html)

For general deployment sizing of your Kafka clusters, see the [Enterprise Reference Architecture](https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/confluent-enterprise-reference-architecture/)

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your edited question :)